# Remove all variables value on Logout

Tags: ios, swift

How can remove all variables value from one place when I logout from the application? Like for `NSUserDefaults` we use below code:

```
/*===CLEAR ALL NSUSERDEFAULTS====*/
let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!   
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)
```

Comment: This question is absolutely misleading. Consider explaining yourself a little more. You are talking about `NSUserDefaults` in your question, however, from what I understand in your comments, you have some variables (global?) that you want to be wiped all at once. Without additional information on how you store the variables, etc., this is generally unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

From a design point, create a class that handles all settings - e.g. I have `XUPreferences` in my projects and store all settings there in one place (generally a class that has various variables that delegate their values to `NSUserDefaults`). Aside from not having various defaults key floating around the namespace, you have a nice overview of everything the app is setting.

On this class, you can have a `func clearAllPreferences()` method, which may (various options):

- you can try using the `resetStandardUserDefaults()` class method on `NSUserDefaults`
- enumerate all the defaults keys you have and call the `removeObjectForKey:` method on `NSUserDefaults`
- if you prefix your keys (e.g. I prefix all my defaults keys with `XU`), you can do this automatically by going through the keys in `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()` and matching those against your prefix.
- use suites - see the designated initializer - pass in extra suite name, and then you can call `func removeSuiteNamed()` on `NSUserDefaults` - which is probably the best way, since it allows you to distinguish between session-related and non-session-related settings and wipe just the session-related ones.

EDIT:

```
/// Key in defaults for myOption
private let XUMyOptionDefaultsKey = "XUMyOption"

public class XUPreferences {

    /// Shared instance
    public static var sharedPreferences = XUPreferences()

    /// Your option, purely based on the values in NSUserDefaults.
    public var myOption: Bool {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(XUMyOptionDefaultsKey)
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: XUMyOptionDefaultsKey)
        }
    }

    /// Clears preferences.
    public func clearPreferences1() {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        for (key, _) in defaults.dictionaryRepresentation() {
            // All keys are prefixed with XU
            if key.hasPrefix("XU") {
                defaults.removeObjectForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }

    /// Clears preferences another way
    public func clearPreferences2() {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        for key in [ XUMyOptionDefaultsKey /**, all keys for your options go here. */ ] {
            defaults.removeObjectForKey(key)
        }
    }

}

// Usage:

// x is now false (most likely)
var x = XUPreferences.sharedPreferences.myOption

// Change the option to true
XUPreferences.sharedPreferences.myOption = true

XUPreferences.sharedPreferences.clearPreferences1()

// False again, since we've cleared the preferences.
x = XUPreferences.sharedPreferences.myOption
```

Comment: i need code like above to remove all variables value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then - you already have some code - does it not work? I've updated the answer with some sample code in Swift (since you've posted Swift code, I assume you're working in Swift), but you should really be able to put this together yourself...

Answer (score 2):

create a class which consist of all the properties of the loggedin user(that you want to clear at the time of logout)

and best way is to create shared instance using dispatch once and than when you need to reset the properties just reset the dispatch **onceToken**

here is the sample code in objective C

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;


+ (id)sharedInstance
{

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

+ (void)clearMemberInfo
{
    //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    //instance = nil;
    onceToken = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is good but i want to remove value of all variable from application.

Comment: So are you saying that you want to remove all variable of all classes  and not all values of single class ? ?

Comment: throughout application all variables value set nil.

Comment: it's difficult... but you need to create a base class from which all class are inherit and than you need to implement remove property method which will iterate through loop of it's own property and set it nil ... This logic is tricky and ugly and ideally you should not do this kind of operation at all it's not needed at all

Comment: The trick, if you are using OS X is to create a new process that handles the session and once you sign out, you kill that process. Or as mentioned above, you keep track of all instances created - i.e. create the subclass, within the init method, add the variable to the list, etc. The list should be non-retaining `CFArray` and in deinit/dealloc, remove the variable from the list. On signout, clear the list. Unless you have cyclic dependencies, it should work.

Comment: Oh My dear Brother, @MihirMehta. You have saved my Job Man! I have created a static Session Manager class for AFHTTPSessionManager and on Session Logout I was not resetting the dispatch onceToken. That was causing Failure on new login. But after being mad for 2 straight days, your simple solution worked for me. Thank God! I found you. XD :D